# Is the definition of a Sigma Algebra not implied by the Power Set?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given a **subset of the** power set of $X$, called $A$, $A$ is a Sigma algebra of $X$ if:

1. $X$ is an element of $A$
2. The complement of a set $B$, element of $A$, with reference to $X$, is also in $A$.
3. A countable collection of sets in $A$ has a union which is also in $A$.

This is the setup as I understand it. What I am curious about is the seeming redundancy between these conditions, and the characteristics a power set will have implicitly. I cannot think of a power-set which would violate any of the conditions of a sigma-algebra. Am I mistaken? If so, what are/is the counter-example(s)?

*correction

Comment: $A$ is a subset of the power set. It is not necessarily the power set of $X$.

Comment: A sigma algebra on $X$ is a **subset** of the power set of $X$ (that is, a collection of subsets of $X$), not necessarily equal to the whole power set. So “Given a power set on $X$, called $A$”, is incorrect. There is only one power set (**the** power set, which is the collection of all subsets). The power set itself is an example of a sigma-algebra on $X$, but not the only one.

Comment: So a Sigma Algebra might be said to be: 'not any bigger than it needs to be?'

Comment: Your 1 is wrong: it should be “$X$ is an element of $A$”, not the other way around.

Comment: No, a sigma algebra is a collection of subsets (but need not be all subsets) satisfying the given conditions. There are usually many different sigma algebras on the same set.

Comment: I see, my issue in finding a counterexample was removing subsets one at a time. It seems they must be removed in pairs.

Comment: A counterexample to *what*? Are you trying to come up with a collection of subsets that are *not* a sigma-algebra? Note that you initially seemed to have the wrong impression that “sigma-algebra” meant the *whole* power set, so perhaps that was really the issue you were having?

Comment: For counterexamples, you might want to take a look at [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). They are not Lebesgue measurable. Therefore, they can't be elements of the sigma algebra on a given interval.

Answer (score 2):

The power set is a subset of itself, and it is a sigma algebra, but there may be others.

In practice, for example in measure theory on $\mathbb{R}$, we don't take the power-set because it is too complicated.  Instead, we work with a smaller sigma-algebra, like the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, which is generated by open intervals.

This ultimately allows for the consistent theory of Lebesgue Integration which extends the Riemann integral.  Why do we want to extend the Riemann Integral?  That's another story.  (It has to do with completeness of the function spaces $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.)

Comment: The reason why we work with a smaller sigma algebra is *not* that the power set is too complicated. Rather, we work with a smaller sigma algebra because the power set doesn't work well with measure theory, at least if you assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: @celtschk  This answer was aimed at what I perceived to be the level of the OP.  "Too complicated" is just the harmless colloquialism that was appropriate here...

Comment: Well, I disagree that it was appropriate. Indeed, the power set is *the* simplest sigma algebra. There's no question whether a given subset belongs to it; it always does. If it worked for the purposes of measure theory, I doubt anyone would ever have considered using another one.

Comment: @celtschk  Fine, "too complicated" is inaccurate, I agree.  But explaining why the power set is not the sigma-algebra used for Lebesgue measure would take us far afield and likely be over the head of the OP.  That's my point.

Comment: So you would say the formulation in my first comment would be over the head for the OP? (In case you object to the mention of the axiom of choice: that half-sentence can easily be omitted). There's absolutely no need here to say *why* the power set doesn't work well with measure theory.

Comment: @celtschk: "Indeed, the power set is *the* simplest sigma algebra." In what sense? I'm afraid " There's no question whether a given subset belongs to it; it always does." is not quite a conventional standard since $\{\emptyset,X\}$ is usually called the *trivial* $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

A $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. As such, it is a subset of the power set of $X$, but it need not be all of the power set of $X$.

Now, each of the conditions you give are such that, if you start with subsets of $X$, you will end up with subsets of $X$. That guarantees that the conditions do not *require* a $\sigma$-algebra to “go outside” the power set of $X$; that is, every element of $A$ is a subset of $X$, and you don’t need to consider things that are not subsets of $X$. So, for example, $X$ is a subset of $X$, so asking that $X\in A$ does not require your $A$ to have things that are not subsets of $X$. If $B\in A$, then $B$ is a subset of $X$, and hence so is $X\setminus B$. And a union of subset of $X$ is also a subset of $X$.

However, not *every* collection of subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For example, if $X=\{a,b\}$, and $A=\{\varnothing,\{a\}, X\}$, then $A$ is a subset of the power set of $X$, but is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, because it fails to satisfy condition 2: evern though $\{a\}$ is an element of $A$, its complement relative to $X$, $X\setminus\{a\}=\{b\}$ is **not** an element of $A$.

On the other hand, both $\{\varnothing,X\}$ and $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, X\}$ are $\sigma$-algebras on this $X$, as you should verify.

For *any* set $X$, the following two collections are *always* $\sigma$-algebras on $X$:

1. The trivial $\sigma$-algebra $A=\{\varnothing, X\}$;
2. The total $\sigma$-algebra, $A=\mathcal{P}(X)$, the collection of *all* subsets of $X$.

I believe this is where you got tripped: yes, the whole power set is *always* a $\sigma$-algebra; but it’s not the only $\sigma$-algebra. If you want a more interesting example, let $X$ be the set of real numbers, and let $A$ contain every set that is either countable or whose complement is countable (these sets are called “co-countable”). It is a good exercise to verify that this collection satisfies your conditions 1, 2,  and 3, and so is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $X$, **the** power set of $X$, denoted as $P(X)$, is the set of all the subsets of $X$. (It does not make sense to say "**a** power set [of $X$]" as (originally) [mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/94696047-ae74-42e1-9760-a6e250ae22a6/view-source) in your post.)

For *any* given set $Y$, observe that $P(Y)$ is *always* a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, no exception.

On the other hand, there are of course examples of collections of subsets that are not $\sigma$-algebras of a given set. Consider for instance $X=\{1,2\}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$. The set $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ since $X$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$, which violates the first axiom in your list.

Comment: It *does* make sense to say “a power set”: The power sets of different sets are different. A power set is simply a set that is the power set of some set. What would not make sense is to say “a power set of $X$”, but the OP does not do so; where the base set is mentioned, the definite article is used.

Comment: Thanks for the grammar lesson. Edited.